# How to intercept and redirect each request on owncloud

Tags: redirect, owncloud

I' struggling with a simple problem on owncloud 7.0

I'm creation an app that have to check a condition and redirect to a page to validate something. My target is to disable service usage until a condition is ok.

In the nominal scenario, user log in, system redirect user to the validation page if condition is not verified. So I use postLogin hook.

But if user try to change page without validating, I have to catch him and redirect it back to the validation page.

I have tried Middleware (owncloud interceptor), but they are not global, so second scenario fails.

Now I'm working with app loading and do something like

```
 $app = new MyApp();
 $c = $app->getContainer();
 if ( $c->isLoggedIn() ) {
    $requestedPath = path($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $redirectPath = $c->getServer()->getURLGenerator()->linkToRoute('myapp.page.validate');
    $refererPath  = path($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    if ( $requestedPath !== $redirectPath && $redirectPath !== $refererPath ) {
        $location = $c->getServer()->getRouter()->generate('myapp.page.validate');
        header('Location: ' . $location);
        exit();
    }
 }

function path($url) {
    $urlArray = parse_url($url);
    return $urlArray['path'];
}
```

It works fine for the first case, but I go into several redirections in the second case.
I think it must exist a better solution. Somebody has an idea ?

PS: I have exposed my case on IRC channel without success to interest someone :)

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do this using `appinfo/app.php` if you've registered your app as type `authentication` in `appinfo/info.xml`. This should *basically* look like the following code, however this obviously needs further tuning for your use-case.

info.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>
    <id>appname</id>
    <name>Appname</name>
    <description>Lorem Ipsum.</description>
    <licence>AGPL</licence>
    <author>Your Name</author>
    <require>6.0.3</require>
    <types>
        <authentication/>
    </types>
</info>
```

app.php:

```php
<?php
namespace OCA\appname\AppInfo;
use \OCP\User;

/**
 * Implement your code here
 * @return bool
 */
function conditionMatch() {
    return true;
}

// Intercept all requests which have not already been matched
if ($_SESSION['alreadyMatched'] !== true) {
    if(conditionMatch()) {
        $_SESSION['alreadyMatched'] = true;
    } else {
        // The session has not met the condition - enter your code here
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the best way, I just have now to display a form. Thanks a lot!